# How to configure a spring boot application to treat empty string "" as null in the placeholders in the application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem where the environment variable that is used in the application.properties may have an empty string rather than being null.

For example, somewhere in the script that launches the application we may have:
`-DPORT=`

and then in the application.properties we may have
`my.port=${PORT:8080}`

in the case above `my.port` will receive the value of an empty string "" instead of 8080

I assume that spring boot uses an instance of a `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` class somewhere to resolve the place holders but I cannot find the way to get to it at the configuration stage to call `setNullValue` which I assume is what I need to do.

Comment: can you show the code ? why not change property to `Integer` type ?

Comment: Any luck with this? We're facing the same issue while setting environment variables from a k8s secret.